# Temperature Controlled System using LM 35

Tags: temperature, system

The fan should start to rotate when the temperature is above the threshold temperature and stop when the surrounding becomes cool. But the fan starts rotating as soon as the power supply is connected and does not stop even when the threshold temperature is changed. NO feedback is being provided. I used 9V power supply. How to rectify this? 
[Link for temperature controlled system using LM35](https://www.electronicshub.org/temperature-controlled-system/#comment-318720)

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: What do you measure on OUTA, INA+ and INA-?

Comment: LM 358 acts as a comparator here. The output of temperature sensor LM 35 goes to the non-inverting terminal (INA+) of the op-amp and the potentiometer which determines the threshold temperature is connected to the inverting terminal (INA-). So LM 358 compares the inputs at INA+ and INA- and sends the output to motor driver L239D through OUTA.

Comment: that is not an answer to @winny's question

Answer (score 4):

You need to connect VCC1 to voltage between 4.5 to 7 v as the datasheet recommend. Otherwise it will not operate normally.[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the L293D any input pin (like EN or IN) is not recommended to go greater than Vcc1 and Vcc1 is not recommended to go greater than 7 volts. Given that you have tied both to 12 volts it looks like you may have fried your L293D: -

[image]

Comment: Funny enough, Absolute Maximum Ratings list 36 V for VCC1, so it _shouldn't_ have been permanently fried.

Comment: aaaaand oops, Vi is not as forgiving.